# how to use dynamic field type in nestjs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a DTO structured like below, the field children I want to it to be number[] when client save the data.My database is MongoDB and I use Mongoose to manage my model.

```
//create-menu.dto.ts
export class CreateMenuDto {
  ...
  @IsArray()
  childrens: number[];
}
```

now I want it's type to be menu[] when the server response the client's query.So I define my Menu schema like below:

```
//menu.schema.ts
@Schema({ versionKey: false })
export class Menu {
  ...
  @Prop({ type: Number, ref: 'Menu' })
  childrens: Menu[];
}
```

menu.controller.ts:

```
  @Put(':id')
  update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateMenuDto: UpdateMenuDto) {
    return this.menuService.update(+id, updateMenuDto);
  }
```

menu.service.ts:

```
  update(id: number, updateMenuDto: UpdateMenuDto) {
    const menu = this.menuModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, updateMenuDto);
    return menu;
  }
```

when I use REST Client to test:

```
Put http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/menu/1
Content-Type: application/json

{
"childrens":[2]
}
```

the server throws 500 exception, so how can i implement dynamic field type? any idea is welcome, thanks!

Comment: you are trying to assign variable of type `number[]` to variable of type `Menu[]` ! how this can be possible ?

Comment: I know, so I want to know how to resolve this strange demand. If i change Menu[] to number[] in schema, may i override it in find method in service? or may I should remove childrens field.

Comment: what represents the childrens field  exactly ?

Comment: It's a menu Tree structure, I want use childrens field to store sub tree's id so i can use pupluate method to retreive the menu tree.

Answer (score 0):

The `Menu` Class has property `childrens` of type `Menu[]` while 'UpdateMenuDto' class has property `childrens` of type `number[]` so here :

```
const menu = this.menuModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, updateMenuDto);
```

You got the error, because Nestjs cannot update the found menu document with the recieved `updateMenuDto`, I don't see any relation between an array of Menu and an array of number so I don't think the field `childrens` should exist in the `UpdateMenuDto` class neither in the PUT request body, but maybe you need these numbers to create a Menu array, in this case you can create a new object from `updateMenuDto` :

```js
update(id: number, updateMenuDto: UpdateMenuDto) {
var newMenuDto: any = {...updateMenuDto};
newMenuDto.childrens = // use updateMenuDto.childrens to create newMenuDto.childrens of type Menu[]
const menu = this.menuModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, newMenuDto);
return menu;
}
```